# Getting transformation matrix giving similar results to Matlab camera setup

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

So, I have a Matlab script that does some work with data and then shows it on the screen. The camera and box are set using these commands:

```
Xlim = [-33 33];
Ylim = [-2 60];
Zlim = [-1 60];

Cam_Pos = [-0.5 -1.2 -0];
Cam_Tar = [-1.7 100 -3.5];
Cam_Ang = 30;

axis('off'); 
grid 'on'    

xlim(Xlim)
ylim(Ylim)
zlim(Zlim)

campos(Cam_Pos);
camtarget(Cam_Tar);
camproj('perspective');

ax0.XColor = [1 1 1];
ax0.YColor = [1 1 1];
ax0.ZColor = [1 1 1];

set(gca,'CameraViewAngle',Cam_Ang, 'Clipping', 'on', 'ClippingStyle', '3dbox')
```

Now the code that was previously written in Matlab is being rewritten to C++, using OpenCV for image processing. In the end I have the array of points in 3D space, that should be drawn over the image and the result should look similar to the one, produced by Matlab script.

Is it possible to get object transformation matrix from this data that if matrix with point coordinates is multiplied by it will produce the result required?